# Android: requestLocationUpdates updates location at most every 45 seconds

Tags: android, location

### Background

I am writing an Android app whose main function is tracking the user's location and making an alert when the user gets near some point. Therefore I need to update the user's location at regular intervals, and these intervals should get smaller as the user comes closer to the target. So when the user is within, say, 1 km of the target, I want the location to be updated every 20 seconds and so on, until the user arrives.

### Problem

When I test it (`provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`), a call to `requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, locationListener)` with any `minTime < 45000` has the same effect as `minTime = 45000`, i.e. I get updates with an interval of *exactly* 45 seconds.
I know the minimum time parameter is only a "hint", but it is not taken as a hint by my app. I get updates with the interval specified until that interval passes below 45 seconds. It seems as though a minimum time of 45 seconds between location updates is hardcoded into Android, but that would be kind of odd. Plus I have never heard of this problem before, and I have not been able to find it addressed here on Stackoverflow.

Because I am not able to get frequent updates, my workaround (for now) is to manually call `requestLocationUpdates` whenever a new location is needed, and then just use the first available location. To do this at small intervals I use `handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, updateInterval)` to delay the calls, and `myRunnable` then takes care of calling `requestLocationUpdates`. However, this method only works about 50 (apparently random) percent of the time.

Does anybody know of the problem, and is there a way to fix it? Or is my only option to set `minTime = 0` and just hope for the best?

### Source code

Here is the source code for myRunnable, whose `run()` method I manually call regularly with `handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, updateInterval)`:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private LocationManager manager;
    private LocationListener listener;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // This is called everytime a new update is requested
        // so that only one request is running at a time.
        removeUpdates();

        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
                location = loc;
                latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                accuracy = Math.round(loc.getAccuracy());

                handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, KEY_MESSAGE_LOCATION_CHANGED));

                checkForArrival();
            }

            // Other overrides are empty.
        };

        if(!arrived)
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, updateInterval, 0, listener);
    }

    /**
     * Removes location updates from the LocationListener.
     */
    public void removeUpdates() {
        if(!(manager == null || listener == null))
            manager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }

    // Another method for "cleaning up" when the user has arrived.
}
```

And here is my `handler`:

```
handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what) {
            case KEY_MESSAGE_LOCATION_CHANGED:
                if(myRunnable != null) {
                    myRunnable.removeUpdates();
                    handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, updateInterval);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

### Additional info

The whole location updating thing runs in a service.

I have read the doc several times, Google'd the problem, and tried various other workarounds. Nothing quite does it.

I have logged the damn out of this thing, and the only exciting thing to see is a big fat "ignore" to my frequent location requests. All the right methods are called.

Any help will be *very much* appreciated!

Comment: What type of provider are you using?  I don't see it in the code.  I get updates about every 45 sec for the network provider.

Comment: @Frohnzie I am using the network provider because my phone (on which I am testing the app) always has a hard time getting a gps fix.

Comment: To be clear the source code included in this question is my current source code, which is hopefully a temporary workaround. The problem lies in the fact that simply calling `requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDistance, locationListener)` does not work when minTime < 45000.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the minTime to any value.  However, you will only get an update once a new location is available.  The network only updates every 45 sec or so on every phone I own.  This seems to be a limitation of the Network Provider.  If you want more frequent updates use the GPS provider.  Depending on the GPS hardware you should get a maximum update rate around 4Hz.

Comment: That sounds like it could be what I am experiencing. But in Google Maps, my network location changes all the time (wifi). Do Google just bypass this limit? Do you know if it is possible for someone who is not Google?

Comment: I don't know about wifi update times.  By network I mean cellular networks.  Google maps likely uses all 3 location providers and chooses the best available position.

Comment: Well I guess there is no point in me trying anymore. Thanks for your answer, at least it will save me a lot of time trying to do the impossible.

Comment: I also faced this problem just before reading this q/a .i thought this is a bug which will protect to show the updates before 45 seconds. Nice answer ..i think it may good if we use both GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER cyclically.I mean inside rooms , hotels we can get the help of network provides also. +1 to Frohnzie and also stemadsen .

Answer (score 20):

You are completely right, the minimum time 45 seconds is harcoded in Android.

This seems to be a NetworkLocationProvider class source code, when it was still in Android core:

http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/location/java/com/android/internal/location/NetworkLocationProvider.java

Look at the variable:

```
private static final long MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_WIFI_REPORTS = 45 * 1000; // 45 seconds
```

And the method:

```
@Override
public void setMinTime(long minTime) {
    if (minTime < MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_WIFI_REPORTS) {
        mWifiScanFrequency = MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_WIFI_REPORTS;
    } else {
        mWifiScanFrequency = minTime;
    }
    super.setMinTime(minTime);
}
```

Now NetworkLocationProvider is out of the Android core, you can find it in NetworkLocation.apk in /system/app

You can find an explanation of why is out of the core here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/10Yr0r2myGA

But 45 seconds min time seems to still be there.
Look at this NetworkProvider decompilation:

http://android.fjfalcon.com/xt720/miui-trans/apk-decompiled/NetworkLocation/smali/com/google/android/location/NetworkLocationProvider.smali

```
.line 149
const-wide/32 v4, 0xafc8

iput-wide v4, p0, Lcom/google/android/location/NetworkLocationProvider;->mWifiScanFrequency:J
```

As you might guess if you convert 0xafc8 to decimal you get 45000 milliseconds

I haven't found an explanation of why 45 seconds. I suppose there will be reasons like avoiding service overloading or other uses they don't want.

In fact, there is a 100 request courtesy limit to Geolocation API:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#usage_limits

But they don't seem to respect this rule in Google Maps app. If you open it and you only active network location you can notice that yout location is updated much more frequently than 45 seconds.

I noticed this line suspiciously frequent (33 times a second) in logcat when Google Maps is open:

02-20 17:12:08.204: V/LocationManagerService(1733): getAllProviders

I guess Google Maps is also calling removeUpdates() and requestLocationUpdates() again to obtain a new position.

So I think there is no fix and this is the best you can do if you want to get network locations over one in 45 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for this very thorough answer. It seems plausible enough that Google don't "respect" their own rule for non-API users, since it is their API. However, I am not using the Geolocation API, so what I'm seeing can't be an effect of that.

I found out that it is somewhat possible to control (and bring down) the intervals between updates by calling `removeUpdates(..)` and then `requestLocationUpdates(..)`.

Comment: You are not using Google Geolocation API directly, but I suppose it is a front end to a core part shared with android network location. So if Geolocation API is limited to 100 request/day free, it seems that there is a reason and somehow they try to limit android network location too. 
Keep in mind that if you could "hack" the system to dynamically set cell towers and wifi access points info you could use the phone as a Geolocation API server...
That is the reason what I mentioned Google Geolocation API.

Comment: I have experienced a couple of times that a new location was delayed due to this, so I guess I will just have to warn my users about this issue. Thanks.

Comment: I posted the question in android-platform google group, I hope someone from Android posts an answer https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-platform/d1YshAsGcsg/ApMtzH_yBg0J

Comment: Let's hope they do! It surely is strange that, apparently, there is no documentation on this limitation whatsoever.

Comment: I get times of 20 seconds update with NETWORK PROVIDER using 0 min and 0 meters.
Any updates?

Comment: Confirmed if you unregister the NETWORK PROVIDER and register again every time you get the location you can achieve an update period of 5 seconds.

Comment: You will notice that the constant, and variable, refer to WiFi. `NETWORK_PROVIDER` uses cell tower triangulation *and* WiFi. A 45-second limitation on WiFi would not necessarily always translate to a 45-second limitation on `NETWORK_PROVIDER` overall.

Comment: You are right, but as WiFi based locations are usually finest than cell tower based locations, I think limitation applies in those places with near WiFi access points and device's WiFi activated (most cases if you are in a city, I think)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. I put a call to `locationManager.requestSingleUpdate()` at the end of `onLocationChanged()` and it forced back to back updates. You could set a delay command then execute `requestSingleUpdate`, making sure to register the containing `locationListener`.

I was trying to create a GPS clock but the updates were inconsistent updating anywhere from 1-5 seconds or so. but it might work for another application.