# location updates using network provider

Tags: android, networking, provider, locationmanager

My requirement is to get location updates every 90 seconds.
I am using network provider for this.

I am doing this as given below:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
        MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
        MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
        new MyLocationListener());
```

Here, in this method, I am passing `90000` as `MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES`, and `0` as `MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES`, so the expected result is that the listener method `onLocationChanged()` should be called every `90` seconds.

But the outcome is the `onLocationChanged()` method is being called first in `75` seconds, then in `105` seconds, then `75`, `105`, ... and so on.

My requirement is to get the location updates *every* `90` seconds instead of different durations/periods.
In case no location is found for given update, I want to get the last known location.

Please, suggest me the way to resolve this problem.

Comment: Narendra DroidWorm Get us your full code i dont think you doing anything wrong in your location update code it will work fine. I guess some logical error in code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the value of MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES to 500 or something but not zero.
2. If you want your last known location then use

`Location loc = LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);`

Comment: I did what you suggested and changed MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES to 500, but still, I am getting the same results.
I am getting the updates in non-uniform durations even now.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mNetworkEnabled) {
    mLocationMgr.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            locationListenerNetwork);
}
```

In my application I am using location manager like this.
See the same problem here:
[Android: requestLocationUpdates updates location at most every 45 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507557/android-requestlocationupdates-updates-location-at-most-every-45-seconds)