# How does LocationManager work

Tags: android, locationmanager

I have been going through the google docs for the [locationManager API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) and specifically over the method `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                60000, 10, this);`

In the above line, the manager will check for location updates after each minute and distance of 10 meters. My question is does it actually take both the parameters into consideration? For example if you are driving along how will the method work? Will it start looking for updated locations since you are over the minimum distance between the two updates or will it wait for a minute irrespective?

If someone can tell me its behavior, it would be great. Thanks.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will always use the interval as the query trigger but only returns a result if its outwith the distance specified in the 2nd parameter.

Comment: So if i cover more than 10 meter within a minute it should search for updated location. IS that correct

Comment: No if you travel more than 10 meters within a minute you won't get a new update until after the minute. Because you have moved out with 10 meters you will get a new result - if you however are still within 10 meters after the interval it would skip the update.

Comment: All i am confused is will it start looking for updated position if i cover 10 meters in say 10 seconds. Or will it wait for another 50 seconds and then only start looking for updates

Comment: ohhh...that makes sense. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507557/android-requestlocationupdates-updates-location-at-most-every-45-seconds this link says that network provider wont updated for anything below 45 sec as time interval. Is there anyway i can log it for verification?

Comment: @user2511882 another way of looking at it - the distance is a threshold to indicate how far you must travel before a location update is registered, the interval is how often you want to check for new updates.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider looking at the new Location APIs in GmsCore.